# How to save data or a set of lists in the application using titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, data-storage, appcelerator-mobile

i'm trying to save a list of data into the application wen ever i want to save a list that has come from internet.

i'm not saying like a bookmark

it's like keeping or saving all the lists that i want, into the phone for future reference which doesnt need any internet connection then

in short if you have any idea about android, it's like i want to implement shared preference in titanium.

Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module

```
list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

Titanium.App.Properties.setList('propertyList', list);

Titanium.App.Properties.getList('propetyList');
```

Ti.App.Properties exist beyond application sessions.